# Sort and subtract specific values

Tags: r

I have two matrices, matrix 1:

```
mot A  B  C  D  E  
A   14 2  3  4  1  
B   2  21 2  1  8  
C   1  2  35 1  2  
D   2  4  4  28 1  
E   2  4  3  3  51
```

and matrix 2:

```
A 12
B 20
C 30
D 25
E 40
```

In matrix 1, the highest values are always along the main diagonal where the column and row labels are the same. For each of these values, I want to subtract the corresponding value from matrix 2. For example, in matrix 1 the entry for row C, column C is 35; I want to subtract the entry for C in matrix 2 (30) from that.

Is there a simple way to do this? I thought about 1-by-1 sorting each column and then extracting the value from only the top hit. However, this would need to be automated as the file actually has 700 columns and rows.

Probably the best way is to do that in R?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add the return to matrix 2;  this matrix consitsts of 2 columns, the first ones having the letters and the second the numbers.

Comment: Should it always use the diagonal or always use the highest value in each row? (As written it's ambiguous)

Answer (score 1):

If your matrices are `m1` and `m2` what you ask is simply:

```
diag(m1) - m2[,1]
```

`diag()` gives you the diagonal of a matrix, and `m2[,1]` returns the first and only column of your matrix as a vector. No loops involved.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming matrix in file f1, vector in file f2 and following script in file script.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

matrix = []
vector = []

for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    matrix.append(line.strip().split())
for line in open(sys.argv[2]):
    vector.append(line.strip().split())

for i in range(1, len(matrix)):
    matrix[i][i] = int(matrix[i][i])-int(vector[i-1][1])
for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
    for j in matrix[i]:
        print j,
    print
```

Run:

```
$ python script.py f1 f2
```